# Size of Doubly linked list

Tags: python, size, doubly-linked-list

I have various functions created and one of them should append data and the size function should be updated after an item is appended. however when i do it, i get an error saying unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int . I'm a little confused to what that means.

```
def size(self):
    self.length = 0
    return self.length 

def append(self, data):
    new_node = Double_Node(data)
    self.size = self.size + 1
```

Comment: Did you mean `self.length = self.length + 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def size(self):
    …
```

This defines a member `size` of the class which is a method. So when you try to do `self.size + 1` you are trying to add `1` to a method, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Furthermore, you are also about to assign that result to `self.size`, essentially overwriting the method, so that’s not what you want to do either.

Instead, you probably want to increment `self.length` by one.

Note that it is recommended to implement the special method [`__len__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) to allow people to use the [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function with your object which is the standard way to get the length of an object. For example:

```
def __len__ (self):
    return self.length
```

Answer (score 0):

In you example, `size` is a method, not an integer. You probably mean to call it, but since it's not a property, you'll need to use the property decorator and its setter:

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.length 

    @size.setter
    def size(self, value):
        self.length = value

    def append(self, data):
        self.size = self.size + 1
```

And then:

```
>>> myobj = MyObj()
>>> myobj.length
0
>>> myobj.size
0
>>> myobj.append('foo')
>>> myobj.size
1
```